# Android SDK r21 - AVD Manager on Ubuntu 12.10 LTS

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk

I have just installed Android SDK on my Ubuntu Device following this example:
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/07/download-and-install-androidsdk-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

The example is for Android SDK version r20, but I set the version to r21 because that is the newest version. I had no problems there.
I updated the SDK and downloaded all the platforms I need to develop my apps.

But at the end of the example, it says to enter `android` in the terminal, and that command should open both the SDK manager and the AVD manager.
However, it only opens the SDK manager, and I can't seem to find out how to open the AVD manager using that command.

Is there a way to set the PATH variable so that it opens both the SDK manager AND the AVD manager?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `android avd` to open the AVD Manager.

Comment: I can believe it was that simple. I feel stupid for not thinking of it. Thank you very much. I will accept this as my answer in a bit.